# Java Class PPM, PPMImage not found, where to get JAR Files

Tags: java

I need help and wanted to ask if somebody knows where to get the JAR Files for my system library (eclipse helios), cause I need to use those classes PPM and PPMImage but the import declarations seem not to work

```
package com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.pnm;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import com.apple.*;
import de.medieninf.ads.*;
```

this is what I have implemented so far

I googled this hard but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Java Advanced Image and its plugin Java Advanced Image I/O Tools: [JAI 1.1.3](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/downloads/download-1_1_3.html) and [JAI I/O Tools 1.1](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/)

These provide you the PNM plugins are trying to use.