# Reading and writing .PPM image in java?

Tags: java, ppm

I have to read a ppm image in java and then convert the image to negative. Then PPM image has a magic number "P6" and then a # Comment char, and then height and width. and finally has 255 character, that is followed by data.
i want to read header and verify if it is P3 or P6.
and then read image dimension and then using java convert the data to negative of the image,
Please suggest me the best way to do it

Comment: Use the JAI libraries. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432905/java-class-ppm-ppmimage-not-found-where-to-get-jar-files) for more info.

Comment: I am currently using JAI to also read and write PPM images but I can't find any PPM classes that would do this. ImageIO with the added JAI functionality still doesn't read in PPMs only PBMs. Just curious as to how you got this working using JAI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAI libraries helped. and it worked ok